# Enabling Java browser plug-in on OS X 10.7.5

Tags: macos, firefox, java, java-applet

I have JDK 1.6.0_43 installed. My browser (Firefox 20.0) has Java applet plug-in 14.6.1 installed and enabled (which, according to Firefox's plugin check, is up-to-date). But applets do not work.

For example, when I login and visit live timing on formula1.com, the popup window just shows me "Missing plug-in". Upon clicking "More information", it sends me to an Oracle page to download Java 7 Update 21.

I don't want to install Java 7 yet.

Is there any way to get Java applets working in Firefox, especially without updating to Java 7 JDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer here: [Java for OS X 2013-002: How to re-enable the Apple-provided Java SE 6 web plug-in and Web Start functionality](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5559).

Silly me: I didn't find this answer sooner.

I followed only the first 3 out of 4 steps (as I don't need Web Start functionality) and restarted Firefox... voila! Java applets work now (I have FF set up so that all plugins start up only after I explicitly give permission by clicking on the plugin's space on the page).

I had in the meantime also upgraded to 1.6.0_45 ("Java for OS X 2013-003") if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with the JRE on my Mac, and it ended up being due to bitness.  My Mac is 64-bit, but the 32-bit JRE was installed.  Perhaps this issue is what is ailing you as well?

EDIT: Actually, what I think this actually came down to was Firefox was 32-bit, but my Mac is 64-bit as was the JRE.  I needed to install the 32-bit JRE for applets to actually work.

Comment: But everything had been working previously...

Comment: Previously to what?  I don't see anything in your post about it having worked previously...

Comment: I've had this MBP (my first Mac) for over a year now. The live timing applet on the formula1.com website is the only applet I use.

Last season it used to work, this year it doesn't. I suspect that one of the many updates to Java during the interim has somehow disabled applets on OS X.

Same issue on Chrome as well.

Comment: So, did Java applets work previously on this machine?  If so, what changed ... browser version, java version, etc?